# Retrieve TF-IDF Values for Textual Documents in CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, csv, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have a CSV file with two columns (no header), held in a variable known as 'dataset':

```
         Year      Document Text
  0     ['1991']  ['FACTSHEET ', 'WHAT ', 'IS ', 'AIDS', 'AIDS '...
  1     ['1991']  ['HIV ', 'IT', "'S ", 'YOUR ', 'CHOICE', 'Ever...
  2     ['1991']  ['ACET ', 'AIDS ', 'CARE ', 'EDUCATION ', 'AND...
```

I'm attempting to construct a Bag of Words model using Scikit-learn and gather the weightings using TF-IDF. However, I'm having difficulty with obtaining actual results, as the output of the code below returns 2480 rows (correct) * 346862 columns (corrected by @Jarad). I would appreciate someone helping me decipher these results, and point me in the right direction as to their formatting (to provide clarity) or correction (to provide validity) so that I can progress towards the later stages of a Bag of Words model implementation.

Python Code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
v = TfidfVectorizer()
x = v.fit_transform(dataset.iloc[:,1])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(x.toarray(), columns=v.get_feature_names())
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
            00       000      0000  00000  00000000  00000001  0000001  00001  
0     0.000000  0.011453  0.000000    0.0       0.0       0.0      0.0    0.0   
1     0.000000  0.022032  0.000000    0.0       0.0       0.0      0.0    0.0   
2     0.006352  0.009717  0.000000    0.0       0.0       0.0      0.0    0.0   
3     0.001422  0.015949  0.000000    0.0       0.0       0.0      0.0    0.0   
4     0.000000  0.002377  0.000000    0.0       0.0       0.0      0.0    0.0
```

Should I tokenize the document prior to storing it in the CSV file? I decided against it due to the fact that I would hope to analyse sentence structure at a later stage as well.

Comment: Short answer, in my opinion, is that BoW or TF-IDF doesn't care about structure. It doesn't make sense to store them in the same data_structure. I would keep them seperate

Comment: But then how would I associate a particular word's weighting with a specific year?

Comment: That is a new requirement. TF-IDF (or BOW, they are different) takes a look at the corpus globally. Were you to split the corpus into years, there is no guarantee that the vocabulary size would be the same (which would likely cause a problem downstream in your processing at some point). After you process a TF-IDF or BoW representation, you rows should be documents, and your columns terms with int counts in the case of BoW or floats in the case of TF-IDF. You could maintain a different lookup dictionary for years if you then wanted to do something aggregated by year

Comment: Apologies for that, I'm feeling a bit lost. I think I understand though, I should process TF-IDF on the corpus to obtain my dataset as opposed to extracting corpus data into a CSV for use as a dataset? I can easily alter my XML-extraction code if that's the case. Also, I just wanna say thanks for the feedback so far.

Comment: No problem at all :) What gets stored as CSV is just a convenience issue.It depends on what resources you want to use later. Based on what you have indicated above, I would do the following. 1) iterate over entire corpus and collect TFIDF stats. Save somewhere (csv or pickle works) for later. 2)  create a dictionary/csv of document_ids and years. 3) Then do subsequent processing or model building, etc. If you need to do sentence structure parsing, PoS tagging etc, just start from scratch rather than trying to make your csv handle all possible contingencies

Comment: n my understanding, TfidfVectorizer it is a pipeline of CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer. 
For building BoW models CountVectorizer is enough, it builds dictionary and count matrix. So you can get basic BoW model as intermediate step and then transform it to tf-idf using TfidfTransformer.
On real corpus matrix is really sparse, so don't save it as csv file use pickle. 

In your data sample Document Text is already tokenazed, but by default Vectorizers expect full document as item.

Comment: By the way sklearn text processing is on early stages of evolution, take a look on ntlk (http://www.nltk.org/) it's match more mature language processing toolkit

Comment: Are you applying TfidfVectorizer to the year column (`dataset.iloc[:,0]`)?

Comment: I appreciate the latest feedback from you all, I'll experiment with the advice you've given and post back here in a few days or so!

Comment: @Jarad, Yes I was. I've updated the original post with the updated code and output. I'm still not sure what I'm looking at or if it seems correct.

Comment: @iliatimofeev I've extracted the document contents by individual word, which I've then appended to a list, which I've then written to the .CSV which is illustrated at the start of my question. Would you recommend concatenating each word to one string (per document) i.e. "test document word contents" compared to ["test", "document", "word", "contents"]?